# Shared Latex: Align adds an extra row

Tags: align

So I have been having this trouble for a while, whenever I use align, there is always an extra row at the end:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    ABC &= DEF \\
    12 + 13 &= 25 \\
    haha &= 345 \\
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

And the outcome is like this:
[image: Extra row in align]

The (4) row is the extra, unwanted one.
Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Just remove your last `\\ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the last `\\`.

[image: align]

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    ABC &= DEF \\
    12 + 13 &= 25 \\
    haha &= 345
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Pukitta If it solved your problem please accept this answer (green button on the left).